# Creating a method to return an integer based on user string input

Tags: java, methods, user-input

I am not too great at java, but I'm trying to create a method that takes input from the user and returns a value. However difficulty always returns 0?

**chosenDifficulty = userName.next().toUpperCase();**

```
 public int getDifficulty() {
    int difficulty = 0;
    if (chosenDifficulty == "HUMAN") {
            difficulty = 1;
        if (chosenDifficulty == "RANDOM") {
            difficulty = 2;
        }else{
            difficulty = 3;
        }
    }
     return difficulty;
}
```

Thanks for any help, it may just be because its late, but i really can't figure it out....or maybe its just not possible to do it this way....thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: when you want to compare two strings in Java, you must use **equals()**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kevin's answer is good (to wit: there's a missing close-brace, and `String` equality comparisons should be done with `.equals()`, not `==`).

But as an additional option: this sort of comparison is a good place for a `switch` statement, instead of chained `if`. This assumes you're running in at least Java 7, [which added switch statements for strings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html). Matter of taste. `switch()` is supposedly a bit more efficient, but I think the deciding factor in most circumstances should be which you find more readable.

```
public int getDifficulty() {
    int difficulty;
    switch (chosenDifficulty) {
        case "HUMAN":
            difficulty = 1;
            break;
        case "RANDOM":
            difficulty = 2;
            break;
        default:
            difficulty = 3;
    }
    return difficulty;
}
```

Comment: @KickButtowski Kevin's answer (which I upvoted!) covered the need for `equals()` (and the missing brace), and it would have been out of place in this answer since `switch()` handles the equality comparison internally.

Comment: @KickButtowski Sure, does no harm.

Answer (score 4):

It may always return 0, for two reasons.

First, you can't perform string equality checks in Java with `==` and expect consistent results. You almost always want to use the ".equals()" method for checking equality between objects. The exact reasons are explained well here:

http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/java-whats-the-difference-between-equals-and/

Second, you are missing an end-brace.

Below should work:

```
public int getDifficulty() {
    int difficulty = 0;
    if (chosenDifficulty.equals("HUMAN")) {
        difficulty = 1;
    } else if (chosenDifficulty.equals("RANDOM")) {
        difficulty = 2;
    }else {
        difficulty = 3;
    }
    return difficulty;
}
```

Comment: Im sorry i edited the post, i changed it to 1 to see what would happen earlier and pasted the code here without changing it back...i have now set it back to 0 in the original post, but i will give your method a try. Thank you very much

Comment: NP. While you are at it, your code will be easier to maintain over time if you have the method return an enum instead of an int.

Comment: It worked thank you. I will have to look into enums, its been a while since I have seen one, thanks for your advice :)

Comment: @KevinWalker it is cool you point out == does not work for string comparison, but if you add what is the right way of comparing two string  in your post, I gladly vote u up

Comment: @KickButtowski: The corrected code had the correct way, but point taken.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you you should use the `.equals()` method instead of `==` when comparing strings.

```
if (chosenDifficulty.equals("HUMAN")) {
```

The second if statement, comparing to "RANDOM", is inside the first. This means it is only used when chosenDifficulty is equal to "HUMAN". As this second if statement has an else condition difficulty would always be set to 3 if the if statement was reached, there is no scenario where difficulty is set to 2. This is because to satisfy the first if statement chosenDifficulty must be "HUMAN".Difficulty woud then be set to 1. It would then be set to 3 as it would not be equal to "RANDOM". Or if the first criteria was not met, chosenDifficulty equal to "HUMAN", difficulty would remain as 0.

I have posted below what i think you wanted. If chosenDifficulty is "HUMAN" the difficulty is 1. If it is "RANDOM" the difficulty is 2. If it is anything else it returns 3.

```
 public int getDifficulty() {
       int difficulty = 3;
    if (chosenDifficulty.equals("HUMAN")) {
            difficulty = 1;
          }
        if (chosenDifficulty.equals("RANDOM")) {
            difficulty = 2;
        }   
     return difficulty;
  }
```

Comment: I try to vote u up, but I cannot understand your second paragraph very well. can you rephrase it ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of casting to UPPERCASE and checking the content. Here the objective is check the content irrespective of case so remove

```
      chosenDifficulty = userName.next().toUpperCase();
```

Then use equalsIgnoreCase

```
      chosenDifficulty.equalIgnoreCase("HUMAN")
```

So that ignoring the case only content will be matched.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with this. It's fine if that is the last time he will inspect that string, but if he keeps it around for any reason, it is worth iterating over the string once on input so that it can be stored in memory in the canonical format. But it's a judgement call.